# nginx load balancing doesn't work

Tags: centos, nginx, load-balancing

I have experience the problem in nginx load balancing configuration. the load balancing server doesn't want to forward into any backend server.

I set the server configuration as below:

```
Hostname                ip_address      role
nginx-node1.phann.net   172.17.45.103   nginx webserver
nginx-node2.phann.net   172.17.45.107   nginx webserver
nginx-node3.phann.net   172.17.45.108   nginx webserver
phann.net               172.17.45.113   load balancer
```

my load balancer configuration in "**/etc/nginx/conf.d/load-balancer.conf**", 
   using **`vhost`**, written as below:

```
upstream website  {
   server nginx-node1.phann.net;
   server nginx-node2.phann.net;
   server nginx-node3.phann.net;
}
server {
   listen 80; # Listen on the external interface
   location / {
        proxy_pass  http://website;
   }
}
```

For addition I also have **php enable** in every server. my configuration is fine and nothing error.

as alternative configuration, I also tried by replacing hostname with IP addresses.

```
upstream website  {
   server  172.17.45.103;
   server  172.17.45.107;
   server  172.17.45.108;
}
server {
   listen 80; # Listen on the external interface
   location / {
        proxy_pass  http://website;
   }
}
```

Finally when I tested the load balancing server, it always show the default web page of nginx, it doesn't forward to node1 untill node3. but I've checked that everything is appropriate. I'm wondering in which part I am lacking or making a mistake in the configuration. I've done a lot of research but still can't figure out why "**upstream**" is not working.

I'm using tutorial from:
http://www.itadminstrator.com/2017/07/how-to-configure-nginx-load-balancer-on.html?showComment=1516785023396

Comment: The config seems ok. Are the DNS names of the http servers already defined in DNS?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, I already define it in **/etc/hosts** in every server.

Comment: It seems that in your setup/with NGinx /etc/hosts is not being enough, I suspect. You can make a quick test, replace those names by IP addresses if not using vhosts.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, I'm running **curl nginx-node1.phann.net** command from **load balancer** it works fine and show the result of webpage. it also works fine for other server **node2** and **node3**

Comment: I gave you a suggestion...`curl` is not testing how proxy_pass handles DNS names.

Comment: I'v already done replacing the hostname by IP addresses, but it still doesn't work. could you show me tutorial how to use vhosts

Comment: is load-balancer.conf complete in the question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72210/discussion-between-phann-and-rui-f-ribeiro).

Comment: @Phann Welcome to [unix.se]!  Instead of editing the question to include the solution, you should post the solution as an actual answer. That way, it's easier to distinguish the solution from the problem and more helpful for others with similar issues. I'd advise taking the [tour] to get an overview of how the Stack Exchange sites work and reading up on [ask] and [answer].

Answer (score 0):

The NGinx load balancer configuration is ok.

The problem is you not having you names in DNS and NGinx, or at least `proxy_pass` by default not getting names from `/etc/hosts` per the DNS resolver as other Linux apps.

See [proxy_pass does not resolve DNS using /etc/hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29980884/proxy-pass-does-not-resolve-dns-using-etc-hosts)

If you are not dealing with vhosts, one temporary solution easier than proposed in that link is in the NGinx configuration, using IP addresses instead of FQDNs.

Comment: I'v already done replacing the hostname by IP addresses, but it still doesn't work. I'v also done adding **http{..}** in the configuration,and when I tested it using *nginx -t* it shows failed.

Comment: Sorry, at the moment lack of further ideas and busy here.

Comment: ok, thank you very much for your suggestion.. I'll try to use vhosts first..

Comment: **`vhosts`** seems doesn't work either for this configuration

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Extracted from the Question because this is an answer:</sub>

Then, I have found the problem. 
Because I left `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` by default, there are double definition of `server {..}` script.

it turns out the `server {..}` script in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, must be deleted or commented, so the declaration of `server {..}` script in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/load-balancer.conf` can run.